# Парсинг Python. Тройной вариант определения конечной страницы

Tags: python, парсер

помогите сообразить. Парсю сайт https://www.spokojenypes.cz/vanocni-darky-pro-psy/ есть три вида страниц-категорий,

1. большое кол-во страниц, где последняя определяется class_='last-page'
2. всего одна страница и в условии я выдаю "1"
3. малое кол-во страниц и нет класса -'last-page' а все страницы определяются через class_='data-page'.
   Как мне учесть все три варианта? не могу сообразить. Если конечная страница не обозначена через класс class_='last-page', то под парсинг попадает только первая страница

```
def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    pagination = soup.find('div', class_='NavBar pos-2').find('a', class_='last-page')
    #pagination = soup.find('div', class_='NavBar pos-2').find_all('a', {'data-type': 'pr'})[-3]
    if pagination:
        return int(pagination.get_text())
    else:
        return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант перебора страниц:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

p = 1
while True:
    url = 'https://www.spokojenypes.cz/vanocni-darky-pro-psy/'+f'p{p}/'
    html = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    try:
        soup.find('div', class_='NavBar pos-2').find('a', class_='next')
    except AttributeError:
        if p !=1:
            break
    p += 1
    print(url)
```

Comment: ну мне нужно универсальный вариант, для трех вариантов, у меня далее идет вызов основной ф-ции для определения итоговой страницы, хотелось бы не нарушая уже написанную логику решить данный вопрос. Потому что таких страниц немного, и в основном все работает уже хорошо.

Comment: вместо print(url) напишите print(p-1) выдасть номер последней страницы или количество страниц

Comment: def get_pages_count(html):
    p = 1
    url23=html
    html = requests.get(url23).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    while True:
        try:
            soup.find('div', class_='NavBar pos-2').find('a', class_='next')
        except AttributeError:
            if p != 1:
                break
        p += 1
        return p  получается бесконечный цикл, что не так ?

Comment: url23=html + f'p{p}/'

Comment: requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '<!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Не пытайтесь переделать этот код, у вас плохо получается это сделать на данном этапе. Мой код просто для вытаскивание все ссылок по url. Обьесняю дано: https://www.spokojenypes.cz/pro-panicky/ на выходе: https://www.spokojenypes.cz/pro-panicky/p1/ https://www.spokojenypes.cz/pro-panicky/p2/ https://www.spokojenypes.cz/pro-panicky/p3/ https://www.spokojenypes.cz/pro-panicky/p4/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132865/discussion-between---and-getteg).